# How to safeboot a crashed VMware image

Tags: vmware

I was working my VMware virtual machine and it started crashing. Then I did the good old "CTRL-ALT-DELETE" and closed VMware Player because everything was freezing (not cold).

After I restarted the PC and then opened VMware player, the image was getting restored until it crashed with the Red cross error messgae saying that there is an error loading this image.

I don't know how I can simply start the virtual machine once again, and I don't need to keep any unsaved data. Does anyone know how to get around that?

Kind Regards,

Comment: Inside the folder that holds the .vmx and .vmdk files, could you list the other files in the folder?  Are there any .lck files?

Comment: @MikeNaylor      Your name sounds very familiar. I wonder if you just retired from a Multinational Company - about 5-6 months ago.

Comment: Haha, I did change jobs recently but not from a multinational company, just a mom-and-pop shop that thought they were...  At least they paid for training on VMWare :-D

Answer (score 0):

I was browsing the internet and I found [this](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2032746)

Also the comments from other users helped! :)

Comment: For future reference, the main two files you need for a VMPlayer vm are the .vmx and .vmdk.  If you have another failure you can copy those two files to another folder and try launching the VM from there and telling VMPlayer 'I Moved It'.  Many times this will boot the machine.  As far as the guest goes, the OS may still suffer from hard reboots like this but this trick normally gets the VM up and running.  Glad you figured it out.